# FOSUser + PUGX: fatal type error in UserManager.php

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

After updating composer, I started getting this error

`Type error: Argument 1 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::__construct() must implement interface FOS\UserBundle\Util\PasswordUpdaterInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory given`

in composer.json I have following bundles:

```
"require":{
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "pugx/multi-user-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
}
```

Full error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::__construct() must implement interface FOS\UserBundle\Util\PasswordUpdaterInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory given, called in /Users/juliezhanazar/PhpstormProjects/cofico-backend/vendor/pugx/multi-user-bundle/PUGX/MultiUserBundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php on line 47 in /Users/juliezhanazar/PhpstormProjects/cofico-backend/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php:46`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master#49e3117888f8ed79a10afe5f0cb7a404c13b616c"
```